# Terraform - launching an Azure virtual machine from a snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to use Terraform to launch an Azure VM (RM) using a previously taken snapshot as the OS Disk.

Here's what I have.

```
data "azurerm_managed_disk" "windows-workstation_disk" {
  name = "workstation-disk"
  resource_group_name = "joeg"
}

## Workstation machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "windows-workstation" {
  name                  = "windows-workstation"
  location              = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.windows-workstation_nic.id}"]

  storage_os_disk {
  name              = "windows-workstation_osdisk"
  managed_disk_id   = "${data.azurerm_managed_disk.windows-workstation_disk.id}"
  create_option     = "Attach"
}
```

I'm getting the following error when running `terraform apply`

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_machine.windows-workstation: Resource 
'data.azurerm_managed_disk.windows-workstation_disk' not found for variable 
'data.azurerm_managed_disk.windows-workstation_disk.id'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Long shot but are they in the same resource group? e.g. `${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}` == "joeg". And the 2nd thing I'd check is that "workstation-disk" definitely exists

Comment: Hi, do you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Azure does not support creating a VM from a snapshot. Instead you should use this snapshot to create a managed disk, then use this managed disk to create a VM. See this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/managed_disk.html).

I tested it in my lab and the following tf file works for me:

```js
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name = "shuicli"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "source" {
  name = "shuitest"
  location = "East US"
  resource_group_name = "shuicli"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb = "30"

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {
  name = "shuicli"
  location = "East US"
  resource_group_name = "shuicli"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option = "Copy"
  source_resource_id = "<snapshot resource url>"
  disk_size_gb = "32"

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

## Workstation machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "windows-workstation" {
  name                  = "windows-workstation"
  location              = "East US"
  resource_group_name   = "shuicli"
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.windows-workstation_nic.id}"]

  storage_os_disk {
  name              = "shuitest"
  os_type = "windows"
  managed_disk_id   = "${resource.azurerm_managed_disk.source.id}"
  create_option     = "Attach"
}
```

Comment: You need add os_type in storage_os_disk. It is required. Please replace your own variable, like disk size.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hey, no dice I’m afraid. Missing variable errors. I can’t see in your example how the snapshot from another RG is being using to create a managed disk that the VM then mounts. You reference the source disk resource in the VM resource, how is the copy resource using source resource id being imported?

Comment: @JoeGardiner My example is using managed disk to create VM, the resource id is like `/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/shuicli/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/shuicli`. We could not use snapshot to create a VM directly. You need use it to create a managed disk, the method is `copy`.

Comment: @JoeGardiner According to your error log, I guess you use a snapshot resource id like `/subscriptions/*****/resourceGroups/shuicli/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/shuisnapshot` It is not supported.

Comment: @JoeGardiner `data "azurerm_managed_disk" "windows-workstation_disk"` this managed disk is created from snapshot or just a snapshot?

Comment: Yep, using the snapshot URI in the 'copy' resource. In my example the managed disk is being created from an image, not a disk snapshot. My confusion relates to `managed_disk_id   = "${resource.azurerm_managed_disk.source.id}"`. If the copy resource imports the snapshot, how does the VM use it if the source resource is used for the managed_disk_id?

Comment: But in your tf file, I don't see the copy process. Using terraform, you need create a managed disk firstly, then copy snapshot to the managed disk. In your example, it seems you only create the managed disk.

Comment: That's because I'm using `data` just to load the ID. I'm not creating a managed disk

Comment: `If the copy resource imports the snapshot, how does the VM use it if the source resource is used for the managed_disk_id?` Sorry, I don't understand it, do you mean you have create managed disk by using snapshot firstly, then using the managed disk to create a VM in tf file?

Comment: If possible, could you share your steps, I will test in my lab and give you the result.

Comment: I'm asking about your example. First you use a managed disk resource called `source` which has no reference to a snapshot or VM image.Then you have a resource called `copy`, which imports using a URI right? Finally you have a VM resource, but it uses the `source` disk resource. How does the `copy` resource (where we import the snapshot) ever get used

Comment: When I create the managed disk. the source is snapshot  resource id.  https://imgur.com/a/H6UZC When I create VM, the source id is managed disk resource id.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the same issue and managed to create a VM from a snapshot.
First create a snapshot of a VM within the same subscription. Then in your TF file ignore the source disk specified above and just create a copy disk with the path to the snapshot referenced under "source_resource_id" and attach that to the new VM as the OS disk. Below is an example that i have used. Also make sure the reference to the disk in "storage_os_disk" is "azurerm_managed_disk.copy.id" not "resource.azurerm_managed_disk.copy.id". Hope this helps!

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {
  name = "myOsDisk4"
  location = "North Europe"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option = "Copy"
  source_resource_id = "/subscriptions/*************/resourceGroups/My-prod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/test-01-c-drive"
  disk_size_gb = "127"

  tags {
    environment = "Prod"
  }
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
    name                  = "Test-01"
    location              = "North Europe"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"


    storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${azurerm_managed_disk.copy.name}"
    os_type           = "windows"
    managed_disk_id   = "${azurerm_managed_disk.copy.id}"
    create_option     = "Attach"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an existing snapshot in Azure,
first a managed disk should be created with snap id as source_resource_id:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "some_name" {
  # option, copy and create a new disk from snapshot
  create_option = "Copy"
  # Snapshot ID
  source_resource_id = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/your_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/my_snapshot"
  <other_parameters...>
}
```

These 2 articles from "Andrade, Thiago" at medium will explain each stages of this task:

- creating snapshot of a disk: https://medium.com/@andrade.th/snapshot-azure-with-shell-script-snapshot-azure-com-shell-script-40ade2bee4fe
- creating VM using a snapshot: https://medium.com/@andrade.th/new-vm-azure-with-snapshot-and-terraform-fa546d6135cf